# not displaying data REST Get xamarin forms

Tags: rest, get, xamarin.forms, null

when I get to display the response, all I get is a null result. I think it may be the class because I am connecting to the http .
Any ideas ? Thank you !

```
public class info 
    {

        public class Text
        {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string body { get; set; }
        }
```

this is the call :

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient();
                var apiresult = await client.Get<info>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");


                if (apiresult != null)
                {

                    labelchange.Text = apiresult.Text.title;
                }

            });
```

and the actual REST

```
public class RestClient
    {
        public async Task <T> Get <T>(string url)

        {

            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonstring);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object type you pass to the RestClient is incorrect. The type that return from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts is `List<Text>`

So, you should change the following line:

```
var apiresult = await client.Get<List<Text>>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
```

To access the member in the result, just foreach loop the item inside the result:

```
foreach (var info in apiresult)
{
    // Do something with info. e.g. info.userId, info.id...
}
```

Comment: Thank you . yeap that fix it .

Comment: quick question . when you access the objects list . the usual thing is ex: **labelchange = apiresult.info.Text.Name ;**  but , I am not able to access those members. any work around ?

Comment: Just foreach loop the apiresult. I have added as part of answer.